# What's so racist in Eugene's line?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, shazam-2019

In [*Shazam!*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shazam!_(film)) (2019) Eugene and his family are having diner:

> Eugene: Automatic top spot for best ever. The man shattered the glass
>   noodle ceiling.
>
> Mary: No. **That's racist**.
>
> Eugene: Not if I say it.

What's so racist in Eugene's line?

Comment: I haven't seen the movie, but at a guess, Eugene is of Asian descent (probably Chinese). The line invokes stereotypes that associate Asian and Asian-American people with stereotypically Chinese foods (e.g. noodles). Well, more specifically [cellophane noodles.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellophane_noodles), also known as "glass noodles." An rough analogue for the purpose of understanding might be saying that a Mexican person broke the "taco glass ceiling" or that a Jewish person broke the "matzah glass ceiling."

Comment: @Adamant your other two examples don't work. "Glass noodle" works as a pun as the "glass ceiling" is a thing, as are "glass noodles". There is, AFAIK, no such thing as "glass tacos" or "glass matzah".

Comment: @Darren - The reason it's called racist is not because it's a clever pun. It wouldn't have been "better" if it were the "fortune cookie glass ceiling" instead. My other two examples don't work as jokes, but they capture what is likely the principal objectionable element: the association of an ethnic group with a stereotypically representative food.

Comment: @Adamant yes I see your point.

Answer (score 8):

His line is racist because it's making a joke about East-Asian people's stereotypical love for [cellophane noodles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellophane_noodles).

It would be similar to making a crass joke about Jamaican people breaking [the '*grass*' ceiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotypes_of_Jamaicans) (e.g. because of their supposed love of cannabis) or French people breaking [the '*wineglass*' ceiling](https://www.expatica.com/fr/moving/about/french-stereotypes-740737/) (e.g. because of their supposed love of wine).

Eugene counters by pointing out that it can't be racist because he himself is of Asian origin (the surname Choi would suggest that he likely has Korean ancestry) and hence that he's making fun of his own people.